# Can we filter data on the basis of specific words?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am making a web application which reads data from an Excel file. The data set I have has a columns which has data of categories and sub-categories of books such as 'Fiction.Romantic', 'Fiction.Thriller', 'Sports.Imaginative', 'Sports.AutoBiographic' etc.

I want the pandas to filter out data and print the total/combined values as 'Sports', 'Fiction' etc.

Is there a way I could remove the subcategories ('.Imaginative' , '.Thriller') and print/display as desired?

There are a lot of categories and subcategories so doing them manually will take a lot of time.

**Actual result:**

```
Name     Category                    Amount
ABC   Sports.Autobiographic.         7485
BCD.  Sports.Imaginative.             20
```

---

**Expected result:**

```
Name     Category      Amount
ABC      Sports         7485
BCD.     Sports          20
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by first `.` only by `n=1` and select firts lists by indexing:

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].str.split('.', n=1).str[0]
print (df)
   Name Category  Amount
0   ABC   Sports    7485
1  BCD.   Sports      20
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)\.') 
print (df)
   Name Category  Amount
0   ABC   Sports    7485
1  BCD.   Sports      20
```

Comment: Hey. The first one worked! Thank you! Also, if there is a value/word which I don't wanna edit, how do I exclude that?

Comment: @divy10 - Can you explain more?

Comment: I have a column which has the words after '.', but I need them and don't want to edit only this word. Say, Sports. Imaginative, Fiction.Fiction, Out of all words, I want the Fiction.Fiction to remain as such while other columns are edited.

Comment: @divy10 - I think it is something else like this question, is possible create new question with sample data, expected output and what you try? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).